# Google Storage Ajax load Json File not working

Tags: ajax, google-cloud-storage

I am using ajax in html to load Json files to that the data will be refreshed every 5 seconds.

When I test it on my local host, everything works great. However, when I upload to google cloud Storage, it gives me some error shown as

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
GET https://00e9e64bac97921ce699e88ff28fbd14910d2de64676b68d82-apidata.googleus…/storage/v1/b/../o/TableGenerationData.json 400 ()
```

I put the json file in the same folder with the html, and my code is sure working,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function refreshData() 
     {
       var tt = $.ajax({
         url: "TableGenerationData.json",
         dataType: "json",
         async: false
         });
       var jsonData = tt.responseJSON;
     }
 </script>
```

I couldn't get it working in google storage, does anyone have any idea?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.

To make it work, I need to open the public link of the html file, and set the json file to be 'no-cache' to make sure new uploaded data will be immediately fetched by the html.

Thank you very much, welcome to make comment and share your idea if I am wrong.